# In $\mathbb{R}[x]$ given linear subspace $V=span(1+x,x^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}[x]$ given linear subspace $V=span(1+x,x^2)$.

a)Find base ($f_1^*$, $f_2^*$) of space $V^*$ dual to base ($1+x$, $x^2$) of space $V$.

b)Functional $g \in V^*$ is given as $g(p)=p(0)+3p(1)$. Write $g$ as linear combination of $f_1^*$, $f_2^*$.

My solution:

a)Matrices of $f_1^*$, $f_2^*$ in base $1+x$, $x^2$ are $[1,0]$, $[0,1]$.

b)$g = f_1^*g(1+x) + f_2^*g(x^2) = 7f_1^* + 3f_2^*$

Am I right? Is it as simple as that? Do I need to write something more?

Comment: $f_1^*(f)=f(0)$ and $f_2^*(f)=f(-1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_1^*(a+ax+bx^2) = a$ and $f_2^*(a+ax+bx^2) = b$. Thus $$g(a+ax+bx^2)=a+3(2a+b)= 7a+3b=7f_1^*(a+ax+bx^2) + 3f_2^*(a+ax+bx^2).$$